# Multiple File Uploader And Viewer php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

I've been spending my whole day searching for a Multiple File Uploader and Viewer plugins , but till now i havent search any, I just want to upload multiple files and view all the files that are in the uploads Folder. Please Help.

Comment: Are you trying to upload multiple files simultaneously?

Comment: no, i just want to overwrite the old files with the new one

Comment: Try http://www.vasplus.info/120.html#.UtZHo4ZGR4k

Comment: i need a plugin that will upload even the folders, like file managers of servers

Answer (score 2):

Try this **jQuery** Plugin I hope this will help

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Read documentation for help or try the source code examples

```
Here is another plugin relatively easy than the above one and clean documented

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/
```

Comment: will it allow folder upload? beacuse i want to upload files and folders

Comment: I don't think so! I have gone through its documentation to see whether it support folder uploads or not (by default) but I haven't seen any related thing. They have a detailed documentation please consider reading the documentation. I hope you will get your desired thing. Best of luck

Comment: You cant upload folders. If you want to do that, you have to zip them and upload the zip file

Comment: do you know a plugin  like filezilla?